# Inquiry about Updates to python user-agents Library

Tags: python-3.x, pip, user-agent

I noticed that the last update to the python user-agents library was version 2.2.0, released on August 23, 2020. As of that version, the library was able to successfully extract valuable information such as browser, device, and operating system names from user-agent strings. However, I am curious to know if there have been any subsequent updates or releases since then, particularly in relation to handling newer user-agent strings that may have emerged after version 2.2.0.

In today's rapidly evolving technological landscape, new user-agent strings are introduced regularly to accommodate new browsers, devices, and operating systems. It is important for us, as users of the python user-agents library, to ensure that we are equipped with the most up-to-date tools to accurately extract and interpret the necessary information from these user-agent strings.

Could anyone please provide me with information about any updates or plans for the python user-agents library beyond version 2.2.0? I am particularly interested in understanding whether the library's capabilities to extract browser, device, and operating system names from user-agent strings remain intact and effective for newer strings.

Comment: You thought asking here was easier than asking on the official github? https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents updated as of 6 months ago.